# How to check Magento Cloud patches available?

Tags: magento2, security, patches, magento-cloud

My Magento 2.3 Cloud is not updated, and I see some issues that when I reporting to Magento they send me a patch already released.

Is there a way to see the list of patches available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the patches available you can run this command below, but I recommend checking with your Magento Cloud support first.

```
./vendor/bin/ece-patches status
```

You will see:

- Patch's ID
- Title
- Type (Custom, Optional or Required)
- Status (Applied or not)
- Details

[image: Magento 2 Cloud patches]

### Applying it

To apply it, you just need to add the patches ID in the `.magento.env.yaml` file, like this below.

```
stage:
  deploy:
    REDIS_BACKEND: '\Magento\Framework\Cache\Backend\RemoteSynchronizedCache'
    ELASTICSUITE_CONFIGURATION:
      indices_settings:
        number_of_shards: 3
        number_of_replicas: 2
      _merge: true
  build:
    QUALITY_PATCHES:
      - MDVA-26694
      - MAGECLOUD-4530
      - MCLOUD-6139_MCLOUD-6211
      - PRODSECBUG-2233
      - MDVA-27825
```